# Is it possible to upgrade OpenGL to version 4.3 on Google Compute Engine with GPU Grid drivers?

Tags: opengl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nvidia

I tried to set up a Google Compute Engine with Ubuntu 20.4 using GPU Grid drivers ( NVIDIA Tesla P100 Virtual Workstation). Since I need CUDA 10.2 for my project which requires TensorFlow 1.15 I installed this [GPU Grid driver](https://storage.googleapis.com/nvidia-drivers-us-public/GRID/GRID10.2/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.87-grid.run) as recommended on Google Cloud document site and here is the result.

```
NVIDIA-SMI 440.87       Driver Version: 440.87       CUDA Version: 10.2
```

I supposed that NVIDIA Tesla P100 supports Opengl 4.5 as it is mentioned on [Tesla release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/pdf/tesla-release-notes-440-3301.pdf). However, after connecting to this VM with a visual remote connection (I used NoMachine), I ran this command [glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"] to double-check, it showed OpenGL version 1.4 only

```
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa Project
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 13.0.2)
OpenGL extensions:
```

The problem is that the application I am trying to run on this VM (Carla simulator) requires Opengl 4.3++, I just wonder if there is any way to upgrade Opengl to version 4.3?

Comment: The issue you are having is because the X session you started by logging in with NoMachine is using a software-based GPU rather than the Tesla GPU. The `glxinfo` output may not be relevant at all because the NVIDIA driver is not the driver in use for the current session. You may need to change NoMachine configuration, or preload a library for the NVIDIA driver to get your software to use the actual hardware. The NVIDIA GPU may also be detected as a secondary video card since the VM hypervisor may also expose some kind of virtual video device as the primary for booting.

Answer (score 0):

According to the last comment, preloading a library for the NVIDIA driver, where the NVIDIA GPU may also be detected as a secondary video card is a good option you can take since you can get your software to use the actual hardware. Were you able to try this suggestion?

Comment: I tried it but it still did not work. I also tried to reconfigure NoMachine to enable opengl but the connection was broken then. I am trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

I've filed a Feature Request on your behalf for the product team to check if it is possible to evaluate the possibility to implement the functionality that fits your use case, you can follow up on this PIT [1], where you will be able to receive further updates from the team as well

Keep in mind that there is no ETA, nor guarantee that this will be implmented. However, please feel free to ask for updates directly on the PIT.

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/168843661

Comment: Thank you Erick. I am thinking, however, the problem is not about Google VM but about the remote tool I used it seems. I am not an expert in this field so I am actually not sure if it is something we can do within Google VM or not, so just FYI.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, although to have a better clarity on what you are trying to do, I took the liberty to make this feature request directly with the product team, maybe they could or could not do something in particular within the VM

Comment: , but they could share a better guide/explanation regarding the issue you are facing, at the end if they share a workaround, that could be a good possibility for you.